# Dirac Delta in L_p Norms

Tags: analysis, functions

I am always confused about the technicalities of Dirac Delta.

On one hand, $\int \delta = 1$, is it ok to say that $\delta$ is in $L_1$?

In fact, for any $p$, does $\delta \in L_p$?

Comment: $\delta$ is not a function but defines a measure ${\mu}_{\delta}(f) = f(0)$ for a suitable class of functions (eg f in Schwarz space). A suggestive notation is ${\mu}_{\delta}(f)={\int}f(x){\delta} (x)dx$ but this is only notation. There is no function $\delta (x)$ and ${\int}{\delta} (x)dx = 1$ is not strictly true.

Answer (score 0):

No, elements of $L^1$ are functions of a real variable.  But $\delta$ is not.  Mathematicians say $\delta$ is a **linear functional** on some function space.  Physicists seem to treat $\delta$ (and anything else they feel like) as if it were a function.  Sometimes it comes out all right.  But saying $\delta \in L^1$ is simply wrong.